# mysql select query with multiple group_concat of the same table

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm currently working on a small RPG game, but I've came across a small issue.

**Unit Table**

```
UnitID | Name
------ | ------
1      | Bob
```

**Equip Table 1**

```
UnitID | EquipTypeID
------ | -----------
1      | 5          
1      | 8
```

**Equip Table 2**

```
UnitID | EquipTypeID
------ | -----------
1      | 10         
1      | 12
```

Say if now I wanted to make an overview of the unit, list all possible equipable types in the slots, say for example like this

```
UnitID | Name | EquipSlot1 | EquipSlot2
------ | ---- | ---------- | ----------
1      | Bob  | 5, 8       | 10, 12
```

I know I could use something like group_concat into something like ...

```
SELECT ut.UnitID, ut.Name,
       group_concat(DISTINCT et1.equipTypeID) as EquipSlot1,
       group_concat(DISTINCT et2.equipTypeID) as EquipSlot2
FROM unitTable as ut
LEFT JOIN equipTable1 as et1
ON ut.UnitID = et1.UnitID
LEFT JOIN equipTable2 as et2
ON ut.UnitID = et2.UnitID
```

However, what I'm actually thinking is, if it's possible if I could just simply make it like ...

**Equip Table** (combine the two tables together with additional column to indicate the slots)

```
UnitID | EquipTypeID | EquipSlot
------ | ----------- | ---------
1      | 5           | 1  
1      | 8           | 1  
1      | 10          | 2  
1      | 12          | 2
```

But then how would I achieve the same result if I were to structure this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cas, as you only want the number to change based on the table

```
SELECT ut.UnitID, ut.Name, et1.equipTypeID,et2.equipTypeID
Case 
   when et1.equipTypeID then 1 
   when et2.equipTypeID then 2 
end AS EquipSlot 
FROM unitTable as ut

LEFT JOIN equiptTable1 as et1
ON ut.UnitID = et1.UnitID
LEFT JOIN equiptTable2 as et2
ON ut.UnitID = et2.UnitID
```

To combine your table use case again

```
SELECT ut.UnitID, ut.Name, ut.equipTypeID, ut.EquipSlot 
Case  when ut.ut.EquipSlot = 1  then group_concat(ut.equipTypeID) end as EquipSlot1 
Case  when ut.ut.EquipSlot = 2  then group_concat(ut.equipTypeID) end as EquipSlot2   
FROM unitTable as ut
```

Comment: But you are still using two tables, I'm asking if it's possible to use one instead.

Comment: How can you use one table when you have data in both of them ? I mean equiptTable1  and equiptTable2 both have data in them which is valid, then how can we elaminate them from selection ?

Comment: as shown in my example, the NEW equip table has a new column 'EquipSlot' that is used to tell if the equiptype should go into equipslot1 or equipslot2 of the result

Comment: Since I'm only using two table as example, but the actual project I had could have a lot more, so I was thinking if there's a more flexible way of doing it, instead of just copy&paste table after table of the same structure.

Comment: @willy_sunny I'm certain that you can figure out how to adapt the information above to suit your scenario

Comment: @Strawberry of course, but the example he's using still uses TWO Equiptable, I'm seeking for a solution that requires only one.

Comment: @Willy_Sunny I know. It's a trivial adjustment.

Comment: @Willy_Sunny- the second example uses only one table

Answer (score 0):

After testing around, I've finally came to find a solution that answers my own question.

So the idea is to use the SELECT on SELECT method to generate the two (or more) tables based on the filter needed as new table in the FROM section, and then just group_concat the result to get the answer that I wanted.

```
SELECT ut.UnitID, ut.Name, group_concat(DISTINCT et1.equipSlot1), group_concat(DISTINCT et2.equipSlot2)
FROM unitTable as ut, 
(SELECT et.unitID, et.EquipTypeID as equipSlot1 FROM equipTable as et, unitTable as ut WHERE et.unitID = ut.unitID AND et.EquipSlot = 1) as et1,
(SELECT et.unitID, et.EquipTypeID as equipSlot2 FROM equipTable as et, unitTable as ut WHERE et.unitID = ut.unitID AND et.EquipSlot = 2) as et2
WHERE ut.unitID=et1.unitID AND ut.unitID=et2.unitID
GROUP BY ut.unitID
```

Hopefully someone will run into my same problem and find this helpful.